# multi tasking vs multi process in a machine

Tags: c#, multiprocessing, windows-services, task

I'm a little confused. I have some jobs.I can do it with many windows **3** services  like service1 ,service2,service3 at same machine  or i can do it this jobs with starting Task **3** times with  `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {//mytask});`

I know, with task i have single process at the machine but with many services i have multible process but what is the difference when using system resource. Which way is the true way.

(all these services and/or start task will listen some queue as consumer)
(and 3 just an example for compare)
(a single job may take 3 minutes)

Comment: Anyway I think that using one process per 3 threads give you better performance rather than use 3 single-thread processes. It depends on what you trying to boost.

Comment: What are you looking for? Better time (as in all tasks taking less time) performance? Better memory performance (as in less memory used overall) ? Better serviceability? Better scalability? There are multiple ways, some true, some false, to Rome.

Comment: (a single job may take 3 minutes)  Better scalability and Better performance which one is good for which one and how? why ? :)  as i said I'm a little confused:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Oversimplified and not full answer)

Process is expensive:

- Process creation is **much** more expensive
- Processes synchronization is **much** more expensive and difficult to implement

But

- When one process crashes it doesn't affect other process that can continue handling their job. But crash in one task may crash the whole process stopping other tasks from processing their work
- Processes can run on different machines allowing to scale over more resources while tasks will always run on same machine competing for resources.

Comment: what do you mean with "crash " do you mean if i don't cache exception or something ?

Comment: @Snr Unhandled or OutOfMemory exception for example.

Answer (score 3):

**Different processes:**

---

**Ups:**

Durability:

As you launch your threads in separate pocesses no other thread will be harmed by activity of any of your threads as they work with their own [virtual address space.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/virtual-address-space)

Scallability:

As you host each of your tasks within separate applications you can deploy them on different machines - make a distributed independent system.

**Downs:**

Resources wasting:

With launching your tasks in different processes you allocate virtual address space foreach of them and may end up having context switches which is not very good for the performance as your machine is saving the core state and restoring it when the process comes back to the context. And it's not only it.

Maintainability decreases:

If any of your services rely on each other you should always keep track on their awailability and coherence.

**For one process and different threads within the process it's just vice versa.**

What you need is up to you to decide.